# C# Authentication error at JSON

Tags: c#, json, minecraft

So, I have a code for authenticating people at the minecraft server url, all I get when I type in my username and password in a textbox is:

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

I seriously have no idea why it is returning this, did I forget to mention something about any user acceptation? If anyone could help, thanks!

```
        string ACCESS_TOKEN;
        public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            return ACCESS_TOKEN;
        }
        public void ObtainAccessToken(string username, string password)
        {
            try { 
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"clientToken\":\"6c9d237d-8fbf-44ef-b46b-0b8a854bf391\"}";

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        ACCESS_TOKEN = result;
                        label1.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception error)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(this.label2, error.Message);
                label2.Text = (error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObtainAccessToken(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObtainAccessToken("My Email", "My Password");
            string code = GetAccessToken();
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Djava.library.path=natives/ -cp \"minecraft.jar; lwjgl.jar; lwjgl_util.jar\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + "My Email" + " " + code;
            Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the code..? is it throwing the error in this Line `string code = GetAccessToken();` or this line `Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);`

Comment: Does the `clientToken` you're sending in the request have any significance in the authentication process?

Comment: The client token is the token being linked to the user for the authenticate check in the game i guess @MethodMan, goes fine throught the code

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed, turns out that i had to use my email to login! Thanks all